# Passing values to requests payload

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to pass values to a request payload but I'm having problems getting it to work.

```
def add_to_cart(item_id, item_url):
  cart_value = '[{ "id":' + item_id + ', "quantity":1, "url_id": ' + item_url + '}]'

  payload = {
    "email": 'email@mail.com',
    "fname": 'firstName',
    "lname": 'lastName',
    "session_id": ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(10)),
    "cart": cart_value,
  }
  
  response = requests.post("urlHere", headers={
    "User-Agent": userAgent
  }, data=payload)
  
  print(f"add to cart: {response.text}")
  print(f"add to cart: {response.status_code}")


add_to_cart(12345, "test_name")
```

If I set the cart value automatically it works but when trying to pass the values it fails.

I have tried:

```
'[{ "id":' + item_id + ', "quantity":1, "url_id": ' + item_url + '}]'
```

Also tried:

```
"'[" + str({ "id":item_id, "quantity":1, "url_id":item_url}) + "]'"
```

Below works fine when I set it automatically:

```
'[{ "id":'12345, "quantity":1, "url_id":"test_name }]'
```

Comment: Why don't you use a _list_ and let requests serialise it to JSON like the rest of the dictionary?

Comment: You did it is correctly for `payload`, you just have to it for `cart_value` the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using the JSON library to construct the cart_value, and pass it to requests.post() as JSON content.

```py
import json

...

def add_to_cart(item_id, item_url):
    # Construct the cart as a list of dictionaries
    cart_value = [{
        "id": item_id,
        "quantity": 1,
        "url_id": item_url
    }]

    payload = {
        "email": 'email@mail.com',
        "fname": 'firstName',
        "lname": 'lastName',
        "session_id": ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(10)),
        "cart": json.dumps(cart_value)  # Use json.dumps to convert the list to a JSON string
    }

    response = requests.post("urlHere", headers={
        "User-Agent": userAgent
    }, json=payload)  # Use the 'json' parameter to send the payload as JSON data

    print(f"add to cart: {response.text}")
    print(f"add to cart: {response.status_code}")

add_to_cart(12345, "test_name")
```

1. define cart_value as a list of dictionaries.
2. use json.dumps() to convert the cart_value list to a valid JSON string before setting it in the payload.
3. use the `json` parameter when making the requests.post() call to send the payload as JSON data.

Comment: Cheers mate this did the job. But i still had to send the payload as data instead of json.

Comment: Was the last part (the code and the explanation) generated by  [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to construct firstly the car_item object and then wrap it an array if needed.

```
cart_item = {
    "id": item_id,
    "quantity": 1,
    "url_id": item_url
}

payload = {
        "email": 'email@mail.com',
        "fname": 'firstName',
        "lname": 'lastName',
        "session_id": ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(10)),
        "cart": [cart_item]
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer, and should be a comment. You might have to collect some reputation in order to be allowed to comment though.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes i wanted to, but i need 50 or more reputation so I've decided to interect with an answer that i will edit after get needed informations.

Comment: I get a response back saying the cart is empty. And yeah i do pass item_id and item_url as string.

Comment: I tried the edit answer and it's still saying the cart is empty.

Comment: debugging [cart_item] what do you get? We need to understand if the problem is on the payload or in the construction of cart parameter